# Bundle.getString() returning null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I'm trying to pass json through a string in a bundle. The string gets loaded into the bundle just fine. but it looks like it is getting the wrong bundle.

in onCreate of one class:

```
    if(intent!=null){

        jsonString = intent.getStringExtra(this.getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.recipe_detail_json));

        //prints the string just fine here
        System.out.println(jsonString);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("RECIPE_DETAIL_JSON",jsonString);
        srdFragment= new SelectRecipeDetailFragment();
        srdFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.recipe_list_step_container, srdFragment).commit();

    }

    setContentView(R.layout.select_a_recipe_step);
```

inside my fragment:

```
 private String jsonString;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    jsonString = bundle.getString("RECIPE_DETAIL_JSON");

    //this string prints null
    System.out.println(jsonString);

}
```

Comment: have you passed the bundle using intent intent.putExtras(bundle);

Comment: no, but I thought the point of using setArguments was that you don't have to pass an intent?

Comment: try String RECIPE_DETAIL_JSON=  getArguments().getString("RECIPE_DETAIL_JSON")

Comment: don't solve your problem?

Comment: no sorry. it's almost as if set arguments doesn't get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must create instance inside of fragment like this

```
public class SelectRecipeDetailFragment extends Fragment{

   public static SelectRecipeDetailFragment newInstance(String jsonString) {
         SelectRecipeDetailFragment frag = new SelectRecipeDetailFragment();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putString("RECIPE_DETAIL_JSON", jsonString);
          frag.setArguments(args);
          return frag;
   }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        jsonString = bundle.getString("RECIPE_DETAIL_JSON");

        //this string prints null
        System.out.println(jsonString);

    }
}
```

And use like this inside your activity

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.recipe_list_step_container, SelectRecipeDetailFragment.newInstance(jsonString).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, but I had to change it to check that bundle wasn't null because I didn't know that the fragment gets created before setAguments() has a chance to set the bundle, so you have to prepare for all arguments to be null.

Comment: @buckithed yes, always check bundles not null.there is many scenario that set bundle null

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
jsonString = getArguments().getString("RECIPE_DETAIL_JSON");
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```